# Easiest way to convert random string to an actual JSON object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following string that almost looks like valid json:
`"Url: localhost/2.0/facebook,User Name: ted,User Value: 4"`
How can I turn it to valid json so that if I do `str.Url` I get "localhost/2.0/facebook" for example?

Comment: pattern of your string will be always like this?

Comment: Where did you get the string from? What if the user name includes a comma etc?

Comment: The pattern will always exactly look like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in the following way

```js
let str = "Url: localhost/2.0/facebook,User Name: ted,User Value: 4";

let result = {}
str.replace(/([^:]+):\s*([^,]+),?/g, function(a, b, c){
    result[b] = c;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yep, great job!  Obviously since "User Value" is separated by space I would have to query it like so result["User Value"].

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your pattern, and any key or value will not contain `,` and `:` then you can try splitting first by `,` to get each **key value** pair and then split each pair by `:` to get key and value of each pair.

```js
var str = "Url: localhost/2.0/facebook,User Name: ted,User Value: 4";
var obj = str.split(",").reduce((i,e)=>{
  var kv = e.split(":"),
      v = kv[1].trim();
  i[kv[0]] = isNaN(v) ? v : parseFloat(v) ;
  return i;
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I appreciate your logic here.  I'll have this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use string replace with the help of regular expression to put the key and value inside quotation (") and then use `JSON.parse` to covert the string into the JSON Object.

```js
let url = "Url: localhost/2.0/facebook,User Name: ted,User Value: 4";
url = url.replace(/(.*?):\s?(.*?),/g, '"$1": "$2",\n').replace(/(.*):\s?(.*)$/, '"$1": "$2"');
console.log(JSON.parse(`{ ${url} }`));
```

```